# Linux random number compliance

Tags: linux, compliance, random

Not sure if this is the right forum, and I am pretty sure that his must have been answered before (I searched a lot but I haven't found a definitive answer).

Do the Linux random number generators (`/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom`) comply to any industry standards? More specifically, if my application uses `/dev/random`, can I achieve compliance with regulations that require the employed random number generator fulfill some standard?

For example, if my application uses `/dev/random`, can I claim that the random numbers are NIST SP 800-90A DRGB compliant?

Apologies if this is off-topic or obvious, but as I said, I could not find a definitive answer anywhere.

(I was directed here from https://crypto.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Does not answer your question, but certainly an interesting article about the difference between `random` and `urandom` in a cryptography context: "[Myths about /dev/urandom](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/)"

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed a very interesting resource and helpful for everyone using either of the two.

Comment: It seems the modern Linux versions do implement the NIST SP 800-90A DRGB mechanisms. For example, have a look at this post: www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2017/08/12/random/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we take a look at the [`man` page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html) for `random` we get the following:

> The random number generator gathers environmental noise from device
>   drivers and other sources into an entropy pool.  The generator also
>   keeps an estimate of the number of bits of noise in the entropy pool.
>   From this entropy pool random numbers are created.

At the bottom we see:

```
SEE ALSO         

       getrandom(2), mknod(1)
       RFC 1750, "Randomness Recommendations for Security"
```

RFC1750 is just recommendations for cryptographically secure random number generations (CSRNG).  /dev/random is considered cryptographically secure, but it doesn't follow the NIST SP 800-90A standard.  Nor any other standard from what I can tell.

Answer (score 4):

dev/random is not even remotely the same as NIST SP 800-90A DRGB. If you want to claim compliance to NIST SP 800-90A DRGB then hire a test lab to test your DRBG and submit the results to NIST's Cryptographic Algorithm Validation Program (http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/index.html) and then it will end up on this list: http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/documents/drbg/drbgval.html